# How do we know some sample is from some distribution?

Tags: probability-distributions, soft-question

I think my question might not make sense to some people, but I cannot figure out how to explain it to myself. Consider the following Theorem.

> $\textbf{Theorem}$ Let the interarrival time $X_n$ be the time between the $(n-1)$th event and the $n$th event in the Poisson Process. Then, random variables $X_i$'s are independent, identically distributed exponential random variables with the parameter $\lambda$ same as the rate of the Poisson Process.

My question is this.

> What does it mean that the $X_i$'s are exponentially distributed?

To elaborate, suppose a computer randomly generated a Poisson process, and calculated the interarrival times. How would we know that these $X_i$'s come from an exponential distribution? How would we even know that they are independent? The above theorem is merely an example, a lot of theorems or examples that claim that some random variables follows some distribution can serve the purpose.

Up to this point, my current 'best' explanation is that if the computer generates millions and millions of interarrival times, and plot the $\text{Pr}(X_i\leq t)$ graph, then it would look like the PDF of the exponential distribution. Is this a good explanation? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It's unclear where your confusion lies. Do you recognize that (after having defined the Poisson process) that each interarrival time $X_i$ is a random variable? Then, your question just boils down to "what does it mean for a random variable to have a certain distribution?" which basically is just saying that the random variable's CDF matches the certain distribution's CDF.

Comment: @angryavian Yes that is exactly my confusion. I guess the certain example might have been confusing. So you mean that the CDF is enough?

Comment: Yes, the CDF of a random variable determines its distribution. (Alternatively, the PDF of continuous random variables or the PMF of discrete random variables would also suffice.) Note that this is different from the statistical question of whether samples of a random variable come from a distribution, which is what dmh's answer is addressing.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you want a statistical test that tells you whether your data comes from a distribution satisfying some properties of interest. Typically, youll need to define the family of alternate hypotheses in order to design your test. For example, you could test your samples for serial correlation , which is weaker than testing for independence. (I dont think there is a general method to check that a collection of samples are independent without knowing something about the data collection process)

For checking that the distribution of the $X_i$ is exponential, you could use a kolmogorov smirnov test. But that would require you to choose a value of the rate to test against. You could estimate the rate from the data and use this plugin estimate to compute a p value for the KS test. Asymptotically I think this procedure should be valid, but I'm not sure if it has any known finite sample guarantees.

Comment: Hmm.. I think statistical test is to answer for such reasons, but the theorem above is proved only by simple conditional expectations conditioned on the past interarrival tests. So, I don't get what the book means when they say that the interarrival times are actually "exponentially distributed".